# Алфавитная и постраничная пагинация Wordpress на одной странице

Tags: wordpress, пагинация

У меня есть статическая страница, при переходе на которую отображаются все записи определенной категории. По 10 записей на страницу. Внизу постраничная пагинация.

Также вверху этой страницы есть алфавитная пагинация:
[image: Алфавитная пагинация]

То есть при нажатии на кнопку, записи сортируются по определенной букве. Это делается путем вставки нужной буквы в url и отлавливания ее в цикле.

Проблема в том, что при выборе той или иной буквы записи сортируются правильно, а вот постраничная пагинация не обновляется.

Я использую paginate_links() для вывода постраничной пагинации. Что бы я не пробовал, суть сводится к одному - функция рассчитывает количество страниц для пагинации на основании показателя max_num_pages, который берется из объекта WP_Query, который я создаю в начале цикла (перед выводом постов). И после сортировки записей по любой букве объект WP_Query не меняется. Таким образом, вордпресс считает, что на странице все еще изначальное количество постов, и не меняет количество страниц пагинации.

Пробовал решать вопрос через ajax, подгружая посты через него. Но разницы никакой нет, так как вордпрессу все равно, динамически подгружаются посты, или нет.

Короче, третий день думаю, как это реализовать. Уже весь сайт готов, и на этом моменте затупил. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Код функции для вывода пагинации:

```
                $big = 999999999;
            echo wp_kses_post(paginate_links([
                    'base'    => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                    'total'   => $loadedQuery->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text' => __('Пред.'),
                    'next_text' => __('След.'),
            ]));
```

Так создаю обьект WP_Query:

```
function create_new_args() {
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
return $query;
```

}

Comment: `Это делается путем вставки нужной буквы в url и отлавливания ее в цикле.` -- не совсем понял что это значит. Но вообще с таким подходом, Вы чего ожидали?

Comment: С каким подходом? Это обычный способ - буква передается в url эта буква вытягивается из юрл в переменную, и проверяется в цикле. Если первая буква загловка равна той, которая в юрл, то пост выводится.. Но как я уже писал, эта часть у меня работает нормально. Не работает постраничная пагинация

Comment: GET параметр? `Это обычный способ` -- ну только он не работает, как Вы уже заметели. Проверяться должно не в цикле, а формироваться сам запрос соответствующим образом, чтобы выводить только необходимые Вам записи и это учитывалось в той же пагинации.